# Regex to place a Pipe delimiter before a decimal

Tags: regex, pipe, delimiter

I need help writing a Regex that places a Pipe Delimiter after some text (with words mixed with special characters and numbers) but before a decimal.

Sample Text:

```
City of Fort Myers ***9999 5 7 6 . 0 0

State of Georgia  ******1234 3 5 . 1 5

Florida Dept. of Revenue ****4321 2 9 6 . 8 0

Arizona Dept Of Rev *****0123 2  4 9 6 . 7 3

Colorado Dept. of Revenue ***-***-8754 1 7  5 5 4 . 4 7

City Of Miami 2 5 . 0 0
```

Here's what I'm expecting as a result:

```
City of Fort Myers ***9999 | 5 7 6 . 0 0

State of Georgia  ******1234 | 3 5 . 1 5

Florida Dept. of Revenue ****4321 | 2 9 6 . 8 0

Arizona Dept Of Rev *****0123 | 2  4 9 6 . 7 3

Colorado Dept. of Revenue ***-***-8754 | 1 7  5 5 4 . 4 7

City Of Miami | 2 5 . 0 0
```

Comment: Are those spaces between each number in the decimal deliberate?

Comment: ...if yes, please edit to say so; if no, please edit to remove extra spaces. Are the asterisks place-holders or actual text?

Comment: If spaces are not intended you could replace matches of `\ +(?=(?:\d)+\.(?:\d)+)` with `' | '`. (I've escaped the space at the beginning for presentational purposes.) [No extra spaces demo](https://regex101.com/r/5YV1iu/1). If the extra spaces are intended replaces matches of `(?<=\w{2}) +(?=(?:\d )+\.(?: \d)+)` with `' | '`. [Extra spaces demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ff4TVS/1). The latter requires that the space(s) preceding the decimal representation are themselves preceded by two (or more) word characters. `(?=(...)` is a *positive lookahead*; `(?<=...)` is a *positive lookbehind*.

Comment: Hi Griff and Cary, thanks for you answers/questions. Yes, the spaces in the decimal are intended.. The asterisks are actual text and in some cases used as the only special characters which proceed the four digit number in some lines. This is why I want the pipe delimiter inserted before the decimal (with spaces) . FYI, the text is extracted from a bank statement and contains over 2,500 lines. The objective is to insert the pipe delimiter before the decimal so that I can import the formatted text file (space delimited) and let Excel do the separation of the values (column1=source, column2=$Amt)

Comment: Thanks again Cary & Griff. I ended up using Cary's Extra Spaces Demo code to insert the Pipe delimiter. It worked like a charm. The only thing I'm trying to figure out now is "How" to mark Cary's comment as the chosen answer? It looks like I can only flag his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the spaces in your decimals are not intended, you could use a sed command to do this with the following regex:

```
cat /tmp/test.txt |sed -e 's/ [0-9]*\.[0-9]*/ |\0/g'
```

This assumes that the /tmp/test.txt file contains the text you were referring to in your question.

Comment: Thanks Griff.. I used the Extra Spaces Demo that Cary provided in the above comment. Thanks for your reply and suggestions.